# SQL Server XML Processing: Join different Nodes based on ID

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath

I am trying to query XML with SQL. Suppose I have the following XML.

```
<xml>
    <dataSetData>
        <text>ABC</text>
    </dataSetData>
    <generalData>
        <id>123</id>
        <text>text data</text>
    </generalData>
    <generalData>
        <id>456</id>
        <text>text data 2</text>
    </generalData>
    <specialData>
        <id>123</id>
        <text>special data text</text>
    </specialData>
    <specialData>
        <id>456</id>
        <text>special data text 2</text>
    </specialData>
</xml>
```

I want to write a SELECT query that returns 2 rows as follows:

```
DataSetData | GeneralDataID | GeneralDataText | SpecialDataTest
ABC         | 123           | text data       | special data text
ABC         | 456           | text data  2    | special data text 2
```

My current approach is as follows:

```sql
SELECT 
    dataset.nodes.value('(dataSetData/text)[1]', 'nvarchar(500)'),
    general.nodes.value('(generalData/text)[1]', 'nvarchar(500)'),
    special.nodes.value('(specialData/text)[1]', 'nvarchar(500)'),
FROM @MyXML.nodes('xml') AS dataset(nodes)
   OUTER APPLY @MyXML.nodes('xml/generalData') AS general(nodes)
   OUTER APPLY @MyXML.nodes('xml/specialData') AS special(nodes)
WHERE 
    general.nodes.value('(generalData/text/id)[1]', 'nvarchar(500)') = special.nodes.value('(specialData/text/id)[1]', 'nvarchar(500)')
```

What I do not like here is that I have to use `OUTER APPLY` twice and that I have to use the `WHERE` clause to `JOIN` the correct elements.

**My question therefore is:** Is it possible to construct the query in a way where I do not have to use the `WHERE` clause in such a way, because I am pretty sure that this affects performance very negatively if files become larger.

Shouldn't it be possible to `JOIN` the correct nodes (that is, the corresponding `generalData` and `specialData` nodes) with some XPATH statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your *XPath* expressions are completely off.

Please try the following. It is pretty efficient. You can test its performance with a large XML.

> SQL

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @xml XML = 
N'<xml>
    <dataSetData>
        <text>ABC</text>
    </dataSetData>
    <generalData>
        <id>123</id>
        <text>text data</text>
    </generalData>
    <generalData>
        <id>456</id>
        <text>text data 2</text>
    </generalData>
    <specialData>
        <id>123</id>
        <text>special data text</text>
    </specialData>
    <specialData>
        <id>456</id>
        <text>special data text 2</text>
    </specialData>
</xml>';
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT c.value('(dataSetData/text/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS DataSetData
    , g.value('(id/text())[1]', 'INT') AS GeneralDataID 
    , g.value('(text/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS GeneralDataText
    , sp.value('(id/text())[1]', 'INT') AS SpecialDataID 
    , sp.value('(text/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS SpecialDataTest
FROM @xml.nodes('/xml') AS t(c)
    OUTER APPLY c.nodes('generalData') AS general(g)
    OUTER APPLY c.nodes('specialData') AS special(sp)
WHERE g.value('(id/text())[1]', 'INT') = sp.value('(id/text())[1]', 'INT');
```

> Output

```
+-------------+---------------+-----------------+---------------+---------------------+
| DataSetData | GeneralDataID | GeneralDataText | SpecialDataID |   SpecialDataTest   |
+-------------+---------------+-----------------+---------------+---------------------+
| ABC         |           123 | text data       |           123 | special data text   |
| ABC         |           456 | text data 2     |           456 | special data text 2 |
+-------------+---------------+-----------------+---------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: I just *plusoned* your answer too, as it is faster than mine (I just added a performance test to my answer).

Comment: And I just added one more answer combining the best of all approaches :-)

Answer (score 2):

I want to suggest one more solution:

```sql
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<xml>
    <dataSetData>
        <text>ABC</text>
    </dataSetData>
    <generalData>
        <id>123</id>
        <text>text data</text>
    </generalData>
    <generalData>
        <id>456</id>
        <text>text data 2</text>
    </generalData>
    <specialData>
        <id>123</id>
        <text>special data text</text>
    </specialData>
    <specialData>
        <id>456</id>
        <text>special data text 2</text>
    </specialData>
</xml>';
```

--The query

```sql
SELECT @xml.value('(/xml/dataSetData/text/text())[1]','varchar(100)')
      ,B.*
      ,@xml.value('(/xml/specialData[(id/text())[1] cast as xs:int? = sql:column("B.General_Id")]/text/text())[1]','varchar(100)') AS Special_Text
FROM @xml.nodes('/xml/generalData') A(gd)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT A.gd.value('(id/text())[1]','int') AS General_Id
                  ,A.gd.value('(text/text())[1]','varchar(100)') AS General_Text) B;
```

The idea in short:

- We can read the `<dataSetData>`, as it is not repeating, directly from the variable.
- We can use `.nodes()` to get a derived set of all `<generalData>` entries.
- Now the *magic trick*: I use `APPLY` to get the values from the XML as **regular columns** into the result set.
- This trick allows now to use `sql:column()` in order to build a XQuery predicate to find the corresponding `<specialData>`.

### One more approach with FLWOR

You might try this:

```sql
SELECT @xml.query
('
    <xml>
    {
    for $i in distinct-values(/xml/generalData/id/text())
    return
    <combined dsd="{/xml/dataSetData/text/text()}"
              id="{$i}"
              gd="{/xml/generalData[id=$i]/text/text()}"
              sd="{/xml/specialData[id=$i]/text/text()}"/>
    }
    </xml>
');
```

The result

```
<xml>
  <combined dsd="ABC" id="123" gd="text data" sd="special data text" />
  <combined dsd="ABC" id="456" gd="text data 2" sd="special data text 2" />
</xml>
```

The idea in short:

- With the help of `distinct-values()` we get a list of all id values in your XML
- we can iterate this and pick the corresponding values
- We return the result as a re-structured XML

Now you can use `.nodes('/xml/combined')` against this new XML and retrieve all values easily.

### Performance test

I just want to add a performance test:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.TestXml(TheXml XML);
INSERT INTO dbo.TestXml VALUES
(
  (
    SELECT 'blah1' AS [dataSetData/text]
          ,(SELECT o.[object_id] AS [id]
                  ,o.[name]      AS [text] 
            FROM sys.objects o
            FOR XML PATH('generalData'),TYPE)
          ,(SELECT o.[object_id] AS [id]
                  ,o.create_date AS [text] 
            FROM sys.objects o
            FOR XML PATH('specialData'),TYPE)
    FOR XML PATH('xml'),TYPE
  )
)
,(
  (
    SELECT 'blah2' AS [dataSetData/text]
          ,(SELECT o.[object_id] AS [id]
                  ,o.[name]      AS [text] 
            FROM sys.objects o
            FOR XML PATH('generalData'),TYPE)
          ,(SELECT o.[object_id] AS [id]
                  ,o.create_date AS [text] 
            FROM sys.objects o
            FOR XML PATH('specialData'),TYPE)
    FOR XML PATH('xml'),TYPE
  )
)
,(
  (
    SELECT 'blah3' AS [dataSetData/text]
          ,(SELECT o.[object_id] AS [id]
                  ,o.[name]      AS [text] 
            FROM sys.objects o
            FOR XML PATH('generalData'),TYPE)
          ,(SELECT o.[object_id] AS [id]
                  ,o.create_date AS [text] 
            FROM sys.objects o
            FOR XML PATH('specialData'),TYPE)
    FOR XML PATH('xml'),TYPE
  )
);
GO
--just a dummy call to avoid *first call bias*
SELECT x.query('.') FROM dbo.TestXml
                    CROSS APPLY TheXml.nodes('/xml//*') A(x)
GO

DECLARE @t DATETIME2=SYSUTCDATETIME();
--My first approach
SELECT TheXml.value('(/xml/dataSetData/text/text())[1]','varchar(100)') AS DataSetValue
      ,B.*
      ,TheXml.value('(/xml/specialData[(id/text())[1] cast as xs:int? = sql:column("B.General_Id")]/text/text())[1]','varchar(100)') AS Special_Text
INTO dbo.testResult1
FROM dbo.TestXml
CROSS APPLY TheXml.nodes('/xml/generalData') A(gd)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT A.gd.value('(id/text())[1]','int') AS General_Id
                  ,A.gd.value('(text/text())[1]','varchar(100)') AS General_Text) B;
SELECT DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND,@t,SYSUTCDATETIME());
GO
              
              
DECLARE @t DATETIME2=SYSUTCDATETIME();
--My second approach
SELECT B.c.value('@dsd','varchar(100)') AS dsd
      ,B.c.value('@id','int') AS id
      ,B.c.value('@gd','varchar(100)') AS gd
      ,B.c.value('@sd','varchar(100)') AS sd
INTO dbo.TestResult2
FROM dbo.TestXml
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TheXml.query
('
    <xml>
    {
    for $i in distinct-values(/xml/generalData/id/text())
    return
    <combined dsd="{/xml/dataSetData/text/text()}"
              id="{$i}"
              gd="{/xml/generalData[id=$i]/text/text()}"
              sd="{/xml/specialData[id=$i]/text/text()}"/>
    }
    </xml>
') AS ResultXml) A
CROSS APPLY A.ResultXml.nodes('/xml/combined') B(c) 

SELECT DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND,@t,SYSUTCDATETIME());
GO

DECLARE @t DATETIME2=SYSUTCDATETIME();
--Yitzhak'S approach
SELECT c.value('(dataSetData/text/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS DataSetData
    , g.value('(id/text())[1]', 'INT') AS GeneralDataID 
    , g.value('(text/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS GeneralDataText
    , sp.value('(id/text())[1]', 'INT') AS SpecialDataID 
    , sp.value('(text/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS SpecialDataTest
INTO dbo.TestResult3
FROM dbo.TestXml
CROSS APPLY TheXml.nodes('/xml') AS t(c)
    OUTER APPLY c.nodes('generalData') AS general(g)
    OUTER APPLY c.nodes('specialData') AS special(sp)
WHERE g.value('(id/text())[1]', 'INT') = sp.value('(id/text())[1]', 'INT');

SELECT DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND,@t,SYSUTCDATETIME());
GO

SELECT * FROM TestResult1;
SELECT * FROM TestResult2;
SELECT * FROM TestResult3;
GO
--careful with real data!
DROP TABLE testResult1
DROP TABLE testResult2
DROP TABLE testResult3
DROP TABLE dbo.TestXml;
```

The result is **clearly pointing against XQuery**. (Someone might say *so sad!* now :-)  ).

The *predicate approach* is by far the slowest (4700ms). The *FLWOR approach* is on rank 2 (1200ms) and the winner is - tatatataaaaa - Yitzhak's approach (400ms, by factor ~10!).

Which solution is best for you, will depend on the actual data (count of elements per XML, count of XMLs and so on). But the *visual elegance* is - regrettfully - not the only parameter for this choice :-)

Comment: Great answer(s), +1 from my side!

Comment:  - Amazing stuff

Comment: cool, thanks. I just don't understand `sql:column("B.General_Id")]/text/text())[1]` yet. `sql:column("B.General_Id")]` already points to the `id`, right? so adding `/text/text())[1]` isn't correct, is it?

Comment: @beta, The trick with `CROSS APPLY` will deliver **the value** of the general id as if it was a column. You can see this in the resultset due to `B.*`. The predicate will fetch the **corresponding `<specialData>` element** and will dive deeper into `/text` **there**. Everything clear now?

Comment: Sorry, I missread the parentheses. Everything good. Great answer. Will accept as answer after I have tried it out :)

Comment: @beta I just added a performance comparison, might be worth to look at it :-)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to add this as another answer, but I don't want to add to the other answer. It's big enough already :-)

A combination of Yitzhak's and mine is even faster:

--This is the additional code to be placed into the performance comparison

```sql
DECLARE @t DATETIME2=SYSUTCDATETIME();

SELECT TheXml.value('(/xml/dataSetData/text/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS DataSetData
     ,B.*
    , sp.value('(id/text())[1]', 'INT') AS SpecialDataID 
    , sp.value('(text/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS SpecialDataTest
INTO dbo.TestResult4
FROM dbo.TestXml
CROSS APPLY TheXml.nodes('/xml/generalData') AS A(g)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT g.value('(id/text())[1]', 'INT') AS GeneralDataID 
                 , g.value('(text/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS GeneralDataText) B
OUTER APPLY TheXml.nodes('/xml/specialData[id=sql:column("B.GeneralDataID")]') AS special(sp);

SELECT DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND,@t,SYSUTCDATETIME());
```

The idea in short:

- We read the `<dataSetData>` directly (no repetition)
- We use `APPLY .nodes()` to get all `<generalData>`
- We use `APPLY SELECT` to fetch the values of `<generalData>` elements as *real columns*.
- We use another `APPLY .nodes()` to fetch the **corresponding `<specialData>` elements**

One advantage of this solution: If there might be more than one special-data entry per general-data element, this would work too.

This is now the fastest in my test (~300ms).

Comment: this looks great. I am currently adapting this solution to my actual data, but ran into one more issue. maybe we can chat to resolve this?

Comment: If this is a *"new issue"* it was better to start a new question with a link to this one. You can place a comment with a link to the new question here. StackOverflow is a Q&A site, not a chat tool ;-)

Comment: I know, but sometimes, when comments get excessive, StackOverflow itself recommends to start a chat. Nevermind, I will open a new issue and link to this one. Thanks!

Comment: see new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60527029/sql-server-xml-querying-query-multiple-child-elements-with-same-name